# python3 setup failed with an error 'Cpython3.exe' on visual studio 2017

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I installed visual studio 2017 on my pc and tried to setup python3 on it. but failed with error 'Cpython3.exe.x64'  failed to install.
Any way to resolve this?

Comment: The valid path would be **C:\python3.exe**

Answer (score 0):

Though the "Visual Studio Installer" was showing error message "Cpython3.exe.x64" to install python3/python2 packages, simply install python3 for windows from  https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
resolved the issue. Thanks.